# Trying to remove the new customer creation area on Customer Login

Tags: magento2, xml, customer-account

Magento 2

I'm trying to remove the new customer creation area on the Customer Login page. I'm using:

`<referenceBlock class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="customer.new" template="newcustomer.phtml" remove="true">`

But its not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your login block name  at  `customer.new (name="customer.new")`  is then you can remove this block by

```
<referenceBlock  name="customer.new"  remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override this `customer_account_login.xml` , and you can do like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           <referenceBlock  name="customer.new"  remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```